# Sublime Text - How to turn on diagnostics

Tags: c++, sublimetext

How can I enable such diagnostics as in the screenshot? This works while writing code.

[image: Sublime Text output window]

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text doesn't have such diagnostic capabilities out of the box, since as the name suggests it's a text editor and not an IDE.

Regardless of that, the [LSP](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) package allows you to leverage the same `lsp` backend intelligence that products such as Visual Studio Code and similar use, and it has the ability to provide such diagnostics.

Since LSP is just a protocol that allows the editor to interface with external processes that are more specialized to the particular language/environment/tooling required for tasks, the LSP package itself is just the interface, and you also need to install an appropriate server.

In your case if you want to use it with C/C++ then you want to use something like `clangd`; there is documentation availble for  [how to setup C/C++ for LSP](https://lsp.sublimetext.io/guides/cplusplus/) that you can refer to for the details.